# Can I remove/hide unused pseudo variables when using CodeIgniter's Template Parser Class?

Tags: codeigniter, template-engine

So I'm using Codeigniter's [Template Parser Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html) as my template engine. It's pretty basic, but it should do what I need. My only beef with it is that it displays the unused pseudo-variables. This is a deal-breaker for me!

***Controller***

```
public function index()
{
   $this->parser->parse('templates/home', array('foo'=>'bar'));
}
```

***View***

```
{foo}
{hello}
```

***Output***

> bar {hello}

Does anybody know how I can prevent the unused pseudo-variables from displaying?

---

CodeIgniter 2.1.2

---

On a side-note, I'm open to alternatives. I haven't been able to find a robust template engine for CodeIgniter 2 that wasn't out-of-date or doesn't have decent documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Phil Sturgeon's CodeIgniter-Template template library, which, ironically isn't incredibly better than the template library built into CodeIgniter. However it did solve my immediate problem.

http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in my own research, I also have not been able to find any *robust* templating engines for CodeIgniter either. When in use, they have an extremely important role to play, so when they fail, they fail hard. Third party solutions are susceptible to bugs, and are always at the risk of abandonment by their developers. The native implementation did not have the necessary features that I needed. These risks + lack of features were unacceptable for my requirements. Maybe yours too.

I offer you this advice:

### **Just use PHP.**

It is practically a templating engine in its own right. Turn on `short_open_tags` in `php.ini` and use PHP's [short echoing syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). You'll carry a couple extra characters when writing your views but at tremendous benefit of having the actual PHP variable/array at your fingertips if you need it.

Templating code:

```
{blog_entries}
<h5>{title}</h5>
<p>{body}</p>
{/blog_entries}
```

PHP equivalent:

```
<? foreach($blog_entries as $b):?>
<h5><?= $b['title'];?></h5>
<p><?= $b['body']?></p>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

There is an ongoing debate about this, but in my opinion, the templating engine only complicates a set up.

Comment: Thanks! I was tempted... but I really *did* need a template parser.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about Template Parser Class but as alternative you can just say

```
<?php echo (isset($foo)) ? $foo : '' ; ?>
```